# Where can I get authentic translation of all four Vedas?

Tags: vedas, translation-request, resource

Translation of Griffith is only available at sacred texts.com. Arya Samaj translations are also bogus for many mantras. So where can I get true translation of Vedas along with word by word?

Comment: All translations of the vedas are inadequate at best. Many portions of the veda are sound-based and not language-based. You will never get a proper translation. You can read commentaries on the veda though. I recommend reading of commentaries by ancient Hindu acharyas only.

Comment: @moonstar2001 That is what I am searching

Comment: @Ajay there are multiple commentaries in arya samaj. why you feel they are not good ?

Comment: You can read Vedas in Sanskrit + Hindi at [awgp](http://www.awgp.org/spiritual_wisdom/indian_culture/indian_scriptures/vedas) (Find links at right panel) but they're not word by word translations.

Answer (score 1):

Vedas are open to multiple interpretations and ancient vedic language is very difficult to grasp. There are quite a few available publications of vedas (samhitas). It is better to opt for Indian authors who can have better understanding and interpretation.

For Hindi language, you can also read Vedas online [here](http://www.vedpuran.com/#).

Comment: @TheDestroyer I accept, but mantra in Rig Veda 8.14.13 also repeated in yajur Veda 19.71. But Arya Samaj translated the same mantra differently

Comment: @Ajay I have provided two links. BTW arya samaj too has multiple acharayas commentaries. try and comapre which suits you.

Comment: http://media.vedpuran.com/Ved/Images/